# Export the data in table to pdf file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, export, jspdf

I am creating a website through wordpress. In that, I have made a table which have multiple rows and contain inputs having same classes.

HTML:

```
<table id="data">
  <tr>
    <th>S.No.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Class</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td><input class="name"></td>
    <td><input class="class"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td><input class="name"></td>
    <td><input class="class"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.</td>
    <td><input class="name"></td>
    <td><input class="class"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want to create a button on my webpage which on click exports the data entered in the inputs of the table to a pdf file. I am trying to use jspdf but when I click the button, it doesn't do anything.

How can I create the button?

Comment: please try first from google : https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html+to+pdf+in+php&*

Comment: I have tried a lot but doesn't get any solution

Comment: share your tried code, which not worked for you ,would be great.

Comment: I have deleted it, but I can tell, what I have done. First, I have downloaded the jspdf from github. Then, included the id of table in the js as I have seen from youtube

Answer (score 0):

it can done use **this http://www.fpdf.org/** **php library** 
tutorials http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto1.htm